# Anomolies in Seaside in GNU Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, seaside, gnu-smalltalk

I'm trying to create an application using Seaside in GNU Smalltalk. I'm running GNU Smalltalk 3.2.5 under Linux (Fedora 17).

I have run and executed the simple counter test app just fine. In my application I need to dynamically create some classes and use them. However, `gst-remote` won't recognize them. Here's my test application (contents of `test.st`):

```
Seaside.WAComponent subclass: Test [
    | foo |
    Test class >> canBeRoot [ ^true ]

    initialize [
        super initialize.
        Object subclass: #Foo instanceVariableNames: '' classVariableNames: '' poolDictionaries: '' category: 'test class'.
        foo := Foo new.
    ]

    states [ ^{ self } ]

    renderContentOn: html [
        html heading: 'Foo'.
    ]
]

Test registerAsApplication: 'test'
```

On the "server" side, I run the remote server:

```
$ gst-remote -I seaside.im --server --start=Seaside
gst-remote server started.
```

On the application side (actually on the same PC, just a different terminal window), I run the following with the noted error:

```
$ gst-remote -f test.st
gst-remote: error at line 330: Undefined variable 'Foo' referenced.
```

I don't understand why `Foo` is undefined. From a `gst` interactive session, it works fine:

```
st> Object subclass: #Foo instanceVariableNames: '' classVariableNames: '' poolDictionaries: '' category: 'test class'.
Foo
st> foo := Foo new.
a Foo
```

Why doesn't `gst-remote` allow this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to define a class Foo each time you instantiate a Test?

Comment: @StephanEggermont not necessarily. I was just getting started with Seaside and learning its subtleties and how it works. I do have a package that I want to install with my Seaside application that allows a user to configure and ultimately leads to classes needing to be generated depending upon that configuration. The configuration would occur when the whole web service is fired up, but not every time the main app page is visited. But even though I may not have that bit of logic correct, why does what I show fail?

Comment: What version of Seaside are you using? Mind that Seaside is not being tested on GNU Smalltalk, so you will probably run into issues with Seaside. If you want to experiment with Seaside, use Pharo Smalltalk, which is used to develop Seaside.

Comment: Those are two different images, right? So in the remote image, you're trying to instantiate an object of class `Foo` but that class doesn't exist there. If I'm not mistaken, that's the normal compiler warning you get when you try to instantiate a class from an unknown global.

Comment: @MaxLeske since I created the class right before I used it, isn't it in the same image?

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. Try this: replace the variable `Foo` with a lookup for the binding, e.g. `(Smalltalk at: #Foo)`. You might be getting the error because the variable is undefined at compile time (sorry for the vagueness, I've never worked with GNU-Smalltalk).

Comment: @MaxLeske I will try that. Also, interestingly, if I create the `Foo` class in the server image, then run the client side with `foo := Foo new.` it seems to find it. That *might* work for what I'm trying to do in the long run. Just not sure yet.

Comment: @JohanB I'll have a look at Pharo. I'm running Linux and I see there's a version of Pharo that runs there. Right now, my actual application (what I posted was a stripped down example of the problem I'm having) interfaces with the GNU Smalltalk DBI/DBD database packages. So I'd have to convert over to whatever I can find for Pharo to interface to MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite. I'm aware of Gemstone, but want to interface to existing databases.

Comment: @JohanB I'm not sure what version of Seaside I'm running, as it comes in the form of a "package" with GNU Smalltalk 3.2.5. Looking at the `ChangeLog` file in the core source, the latest date entry is: 2011-05-26  Paolo Bonzini  <bonzini@gnu.org>

        * core/Seaside-Core.st: Convert output of #selectors to an Array
        before building filenames.  Reported by Gwenael Casaccio.

Answer (score 0):

GST is not really a first-class citizen for Seaside development, so your best bet for getting this working is to do the first steps of Seaside development in a Pharo image, and then exporting that code to GST. You are likely to run into some issue where changes have been made to Seaside since 2011. Once your understanding of Seaside (in Pharo) is better, it will likely not be too much work to port to GST. If you do the exporting to GST in a CI setup, we'll be able to help you with concrete questions on the Seaside or Seaside-dev mailing lists.